# Get all combinations of an unknown length string

Tags: python

Let's say I have a python string `myStr = "abc"` and I want to find the all combinations, even if I don't know the length of the string. I am fine with itertools being used. I need an output like

```
a
ab
abc
b
ba
```

ect.

Comment: If you know about itertools, then I don't understand why you're bothering to ask us...

Comment: etc. = et cetera

Comment: What does "ect." stand for? You need to enumerate all the outputs. If you were looking for combinations proper, `ba` wouldn't be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import itertools

s = 'abc'
for i in range(len(s)+1):
    perms = itertools.permutations(s,i)
    for perm in perms:
        print(''.join(perm))
```

Output:

```
a
b
c
ab
ac
ba
bc
ca
cb
abc
acb
bac
bca
cab
cba
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have (Count of available chars+an empty char)^length loop to fully calculate possiblities . you can use circular definition functions with a good algorithm ,  or define a class to set returned words properties like Length or uniqueness , ..

Answer (score 0):

Here's the complete answer if you still need it:

```
from collections import deque

chars = deque(['_','a', 'b','c'])
        
def innerLoopCall(original_list=[],list_to_add_item=[],len_of_given_list=0,list_combinations=[]):   
    num,  count = int(len(list_to_add_item)), 0
    c=''
    
    if(len_of_given_list>=0):
        for i in range(1, len(original_list)+1):
            for a in range(1, len(list_to_add_item)+1):
                d =original_list[i-1]+list_to_add_item[a-1]# i+a
                to_add=d.replace("_","")
                if(len(to_add)<=len(original_list)-1):
                    if(to_add not in list_combinations):
                        list_combinations.append(to_add)
                    for letter in d:
                        count += 1
                    c = c + original_list[i-1]+list_to_add_item[a-1] + ' '*(5-count)#divide combinations in table



                
                count = 0
            #c = c + '\n   ' #to see multiplication table uncomment
        #print(c)#to see multiplication table uncomment
        len_of_given_list-=1
        innerLoopCall(original_list,list_combinations,len_of_given_list,list_combinations)
        
    list_combinations.sort()
    return list_combinations
    
    
  
                
test=[]
result=innerLoopCall(chars,chars,len(chars),test)
print("total unique probabilities count is: "+str(len(result)-1))
result
```

and this is the output:

```
total unique probabilities count is: 39
['',
 'a',
 'aa',
 'aaa',
 'aab',
 'aac',
 'ab',
 'aba',
 'abb',
 'abc',
 'ac',
 'aca',
 'acb',
 'acc',
 'b',
 'ba',
 'baa',
 'bab',
 'bac',
 'bb',
 'bba',
 'bbb',
 'bbc',
 'bc',
 'bca',
 'bcb',
 'bcc',
 'c',
 'ca',
 'caa',
 'cab',
 'cac',
 'cb',
 'cba',
 'cbb',
 'cbc',
 'cc',
 'cca',
 'ccb',
 'ccc']
```